# Custom Control: "Lifecycle-Method" when aggregation is updated

Tags: sapui5

I am creating a simple custom control:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/Control"
], function(Control) {
  "use strict";

  return Control.extend("my.control.SvgVisualizer", {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        width: {
          type: "sap.ui.core.CSSSize",
          defaultValue: "100%"
        },
        height: {
          type: "sap.ui.core.CSSSize",
          defaultValue: "100%"
        }
      },
      aggregations: {
        elements: {
          type: "my.control.Element",
          multiple: true,
          singularName: "element"
        }
      }
    },

    renderer: {
      apiVersion: 2,
      render: function(oRm, oControl) {
        oRm.openStart("svg", oControl.getId())
          .attr("viewBox", oControl._sViewBox)
          .attr("width", oControl.getWidth())
          .attr("height", oControl.getHeight())
          .openEnd();
        oRm.close("svg");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Basically, it can be used to implement svg stuff with aggregations into SAPUI5.
When creating the svg (html)-element in the  `renderer` function I need a `viewBox`.

I would like to calculate the value for the `viewBox` based on the properties of the controls in the aggregation `elements`. The calculation could be pretty heavy if there are loads of `elements`.

My question is where I should calculate the `viewBox` property. It needs to be recalculated when the aggregation `elements` changes (so `init` isn't enough) but it does not need to be recalculated every time the `renderer` function is called.

Is attaching a handler to the aggregation-binding in the `constructor` the best way: `this.getBinding("elements").attachChange(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to override all the aggregation modifiers like `addElement`, `removeElement`, ...etc and recalculate there.
But I would suggest to implement some kind of change detection for the `elements` aggregation in the `onBeforeRendering` hook and perform calculations only if the aggregation has changed. This way you don't need to worry if you have overridden all the modifiers correctly and you have the implementation on a single place. For example:

```js
onBeforeRendering: function () {
    var currElements = this.getElements();
    var recalculate = false;

    if (!this._oldElements) {
        recalculate = true;
    } else if (this._oldElements.length !== currElements.length) {
        recalculate = true;
    } else if (... another condition that should trigger recalculation) {
        recalculate = true;
    }

    if (recalculate) {
        this._sViewBox = ...;
        this._oldElements = currElements;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I am using XML Views to create the control. Are the aggregation modifiers called when using a model to bind the elements aggregation to the control? About the second part… Is attachChange the correct way to implement change detection?

Comment: Yes, generated aggregation modifiers are the "official"  API to your control and they are used by the binding as well.  Adding an event listener to the binding won't work if the aggregation is modified another way. To follow the principle of abstraction your control shouldn't know where its data is coming from. I have added an example for the `onBeforeRendering` way. You can read more about aggregations [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#overview)